# Why my diagonal dots become 6 dots rather than 3?

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent,nullify-dots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
$\begin{bmatrix}
d_1 &  \ast&  \ast&  \ast&  \ast&  \ast\\ 
 c_1&  d_2&   \ast&   \ast&   \ast&   \ast\\
 0&  c_2&  d_3&   \ast&   \ast&   \ast\\
 0  &   0&   c_3&   d_4   &   \ast&    \ast\\
 0   &0   &0   &\ddots   &\ddots   &\ast\\  
 0&0&0&0&c_{n-1}&d_n
\end{bmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please fix your example code so that it is a complete document that produces the image shown.

Comment: Your dots is caused by use of the `nicematrix` package and set its option `\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent,nullify-dots}` in preamble. I suggest to insert this option in group` where is used `nicematrix`, where you like to have such format of `dots`.

Comment: Not related: You don't need any longer `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with recent LaTeX versions.

Answer (score 9):

(I'm the author of `nicematrix`).

I recommend to use the option `transparent` only when one has a whole document with many matrices with dotted lines and want to use quickly the dotted lines provided by `nicematrix` (without changing the code of the document for each matrix with dotted lines).

For new documents, I recommend to use `{pmatrix}` of `amsmath` and to use `{pNiceMatrix}` only when one of the features provided by `nicematrix` is needed.

The recent versions of `nicematrix` provides other features than the dotted lines and that's why I have written in the documentation that the key `transparent` is now obsolete (the name of that key is no longer meaningful with the recent versions of `nicematrix`). However, the keys `renew-dots` and `renew-matrix` are *not* obsolete and will still be available for the interested users...

Comment: Thank you for explanation (+1). Your package recently (a year or so) fast evolved, so it is difficult to follows to all novelties regardless to good documentation which become larger with any new package version :-). Thank you for this interesting and usable package!

Comment: @Zarko ...is in continuous evolution but we also vote positively his answer :-)

Answer (score 7):

Let me extend my comment:

- Cause of your problem is `\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent,nullify-dots}` which you put in preamble, so it influence on all matrices in document.
- You should move it to where is needed so that it has effect only locally
- As mentioned in nice [@muzimuzhi Z  answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572359/why-my-diagonal-dots-become-6-dots-rather-than-3/572377#572377) option `transparent` is obsolete in the recent version of `nicematrix` package.

MWE, which demonstrate, how you can write your matrices is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathdots}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
%\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent,nullify-dots}


\begin{document}
Standard `bmatrix`, the final result is visible already after one compilation
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
d_1 &  \ast&  \ast&  \ast&  \ast&  \ast\\
 c_1&  d_2&   \ast&   \ast&   \ast&   \ast\\
 0&  c_2&  d_3&   \ast&   \ast&   \ast\\
 0  &   0&   c_3&   d_4   &   \ast&    \ast\\
 0   &0   &0   &\ddots   &\ddots   &\ast\\
 0&0&0&0&c_{n-1}&d_n
\end{bmatrix}
\]
Use of `bNiceMatrix`, the final result is visible already after two compilations
\[\NiceMatrixOptions{nullify-dots}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
d_1 &  \ast&  \ast&  \ast&  \ast&  \ast\\
 c_1&  d_2&   \ast&   \ast&   \ast&   \ast\\
 0&  c_2&  d_3&   \ast&   \ast&   \ast\\
 0  &   0&   c_3&   d_4   &   \ast&    \ast\\
 0   &0   &0   &\Ddots   &\Ddots   &\ast\\
 0&0&0&0&c_{n-1}&d_n
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What you get is exactly the effect of `transparent` and `nullify-dots`, two `nicematrix` options set by `\NiceMatrixOptions{<options>}`.

- `transparent` is an *obsolete* option. It is the conjunction of options `renew-dots` and `renew-matrix`. See doc of `nicemtrix`, sec. 9.3.

  - `renew-dots` redefines dots commands like `\ddots` (used in `nicematrix` environments) to act like their `nicematrix` continuous variant like `\Ddots`.
  - `renew-matrix` redefines `matrix` environment, the base of every other matrix env with delimiters like `pmatrix`, to act like `nicematrix` env `NiceMatrix`.
  - The total effect is that using `\ddots` in `pmatrix` will get continuous dots (normally more than three), according to the space for dots.
- `nullify-dots` sets both the height and width of continuous dots to zero, so that they will not enlarge the whole matrix. See doc of `nicematrix`, sec. 9.1.

  - This gives you only six dots per `\ddots` in your example, otherwise you get more.